Removing undermount sink
I am trying to remove a cracked undermount sink but whatever adhesive was used isn't budging for me. From the inside of the sink it looks like more gray (hard to see in the picture, but the dust there is from going at it with a multitool). On the outside it is yellowish. The adhesive is rock hard on both sides.
Things I've tried mechanical removal with a paint scraper, razor, and oscillating multitool. Along with:

Heat
Petroleum jelly (left on over night)
WD40
Acetone
Rubbing alcohol
Mineral spirits

Looking for thoughts about what I might be dealing with here and any suggestions on what to try.


Remember the goal is to save the benchtop, and plumbing/taps.  The sink-bowl is damaged, will go into the trash and can be destroyed during removal.

There is probably epoxy used to mount the sink. It will not likely come apart. You may want to try to break the sink, remove the pieces and grind off the epoxy.

I agree with RMDman that this is epoxy. You don't remove epoxy with solvents. It's a mechanical job.
One way to free the bulk of the sink before you grind the rest away would be to drill a series of small horizontal holes below the entire rim, creating a line of weakness. Then pry with a robust tool and/or drive a chisel into the line to crack it loose.
An angle grinder would help remove material and clean up the surface for the next sink, but use caution--it'll put permanent scars in your top in the blink of an eye.
Use eye and ear protection.
